# How to get a variable with a different value for each marker (from JSON)

Tags: android, json, google-maps

My application show a map with markers loaded from a JSON file, and when you click a marker it ask "Would you like to call ?". Then the phone call is made to the person located by the marker.
But with this code, all markers call the same number, the last one on my JSON file. 
So how can I pass a different phone number (phone) corresponding with the person to each marker?
Thank you :)

```
 protected void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
 map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new Balloon(getLayoutInflater()));

 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
 // Create a marker for each person in the JSON data.
 JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
           .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
           .snippet(jsonObj.getString("dispo"))
           .position(new LatLng(
                   jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0),
                   jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(1)))
           .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin)));

    phone =  Uri.parse("tel:+33" + jsonObj.getString("phone"));

    map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, phone);
                 startActivity(callIntent);
      }});

    }
}
```

Comment: If your `OnInfoWindowClickListener` method is in `for` loop then just put it out of `for` loop. Also add your phone number to hashmap arraylist and retrieve it by its position.

Comment: Ya I tried but I have the same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a HashMap that will link your markers to phone Uris:

```
HashMap<Marker, Uri> phones = new HashMap<>();

protected void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
    map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new Balloon(getLayoutInflater()));

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        // Create a marker for each person in the JSON data.
        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
                .snippet(jsonObj.getString("dispo"))
                .position(new LatLng(
                        jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0),
                        jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(1)))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin)));

        phones.put(marker, Uri.parse("tel:+33" + jsonObj.getString("phone")));
    }

    map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, phones.get(marker));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: But the expression marker can't be solved here:             phones.put(marker, Uri.parse("tel:+33" + jsonObj.getString("phone")));

Comment: This did not work for me. Balloon undeclared and still only got the first result because it makes me declare the Hashmap Final